# Prevent rounding (or at least length overflow) when logging floats (specifically "msecs") using f-string style format specification

Tags: python, logging, f-string

A bit of background:

The Python [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html?highlight=msec#logrecord-attributes) say:

> In the case of `{}`-formatting, you can specify formatting flags by placing them after the attribute name, separated from it with a colon. For example: a placeholder of `{msecs:03d}` would format a millisecond value of 4 as 004.

However, this does *not* work, since the logging record's `msecs` value is actually a `float`:

```
>>> record.msecs
275.38108825683594
```

so trying to use the example `{}` formatting in the docs raises a `ValueError`:

```
>>> f'{record.msecs:03d}'
*** ValueError: Unknown format code 'd' for object of type 'float'
```

Old-style `%`-formating with `03d` works fine for a `float`:

```
>>> '%03d' % record.msecs
'275'
```

---

Based on the above findings, I used a `float` format specification in my logging definition, like this:

```py
logging.basicConfig(
    level=logging.INFO,
    format="{asctime}.{msecs:0>3.0f} [{levelname:.1s}] {message}",
    datefmt="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",
    style="{",
)
```

which seemed to be working well, until I noticed this log entry:

```
2021-03-25 22:37:18.993 [I] ...
2021-03-25 22:37:18.997 [I] ...
2021-03-25 22:37:18.1000 [I] ...
2021-03-25 22:37:19.002 [I] ...
2021-03-25 22:37:19.004 [I] ...
```

which happens when the logging record's `msecs` float value is >= 999.5:

```
>>> t1 = 999.499999
>>> t2 = 999.5
>>> print(f"{t1:0>3.0f} {t2:0>3.0f}")
999 1000
```

Obviously I'd prefer `.1000` to be logged as `.000` (rounding *without* overflowing the 3-digit length) if there was a way to also increment the `{asctime}` part of the timestamp by a second. **But** I'd be fine with just logging `.999` (truncating to `int` instead of rounding) since this overflow only happens a very small percent of the time, and for my purposes this logging isn't *that* critical.

Any way to do this, *other* than going back to old-style `%`-based formatting?

Comment: Obviously changing 1000 to 0 would make your record off by a whole second... can you not format the entire record.created as a time as opposed to individual parts? (Refreshing to see a well thought out question btw!)

Comment: Sorry just noticed I think you are doing this in second snippet.. ( on mobile atm, will check later if still needed)

Comment: That's a very good point about logging `.1000` as `.000`!

Comment: This was [reported and fixed from Python 3.10 onward](https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/89047).  It's still a float, but can no longer be 1000.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can override the [default millisecond format](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.Formatter.formatTime):

```
logging.basicConfig(
    level=logging.INFO,
    format="{asctime} ...{msecs:3.1f} ...{msecs:3.0f} [{levelname:.1s}] {message}",
    # datefmt="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",
    style="{",
)
logging.Formatter.default_msec_format = '%s.%03d'
```

I think that achieves what you want the milliseconds are truncated to three digits. Unfortunately specifying `datefmt` messes that up and the milliseconds don't display.

---

Here are custom `converter` and `formatTime` functions that can be used to replace the default Formatter methods. These will allow you to specify the datefmt in the configuration. They work together so they both have to be used.

```
import logging

def converter(self,t):
    '''Returns a tuple (time.struct_time, int)
    '''

    # separate seconds from fractional seconds 
    # round the fraction,
    # adjust the seconds if needed
    # turn the fraction into an integer
    seconds = int(t)
    msec = round(t - seconds,3)
    if msec > .9995:
        msec = 0
        seconds += 1
    else:
        msec = int(1000 * msec)
    # parts = list(time.localtime(seconds))
    # parts[-2] = msec
    t = time.localtime(seconds)
    return t,msec

def formatTime(self, record, datefmt=None):
    """
    Return the creation time of the specified LogRecord as formatted text.
    This method should be called from format() by a formatter which
    wants to make use of a formatted time. This method expects the
    converter to return a (time.struct_time,int) tuple where the int is
    between 0 and 999.
    The int is the rounded msec of the record's creation time.
    """
    ct,msec = self.converter(record.created)
    if datefmt:
        s = time.strftime(datefmt, ct)
    else:
        s = time.strftime(self.default_time_format, ct)
    s = f'{s}.{msec:03d}'
    return s

logging.basicConfig(
    level=logging.INFO,
    format="{asctime} | {message}",
    datefmt="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",
    style="{",
)

logging.Formatter.converter = converter
logging.Formatter.formatTime = formatTime
logging.info('foo')
```

That log looks like:

```
2021-03-27 16:12:05.498 | foo
```

---

If the datefmt argument does not end with the seconds then tacking on the milliseconds would be silly so maybe that should be checked for.

```
def formatTime(self, record, datefmt=None):
    """
    Return the creation time of the specified LogRecord as formatted text.
    This method should be called from format() by a formatter which
    wants to make use of a formatted time. This method expects the
    converter to return a (time.struct_time,int) tuple where the int is
    between 0 and 999.
    The int is the rounded msec of the record's creation time.
    """
    ct,msec = self.converter(record.created)
    if datefmt:
        s = time.strftime(datefmt, ct)
    else:
        s = time.strftime(self.default_time_format, ct)
        # s = f'{s}.{msec:03d}'
        # if self.default_msec_format:
        #     s = self.default_msec_format % (s, record.msecs)
    if datefmt[-1] == 'S':
        s = f'{s}.{msec:03d}'
    return s
```

Comment: Thanks! This approach does seem to achieve what I want. It is a bummer you are "stuck" with the default `datefmt`. I'd still be interested in a more "generic" solution!

Comment: @eddyg I think with a bit more effort a generic solution could be found. It would probably entail writing a Formatter and a Handler and maybe a custom time converter for the Formatter.

Comment: Wow, thanks for taking the time to post a thorough solution!!